# Will I have trouble after upgrade?

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, 13.04

I have Ubuntu 12.10 with installed Gnome 3, and Unity removed, I just want to ask if there will be any problems after dist-upgrade, or it has nothing to do with which window manager I use. Should I back-up anything?

Comment: If you have custom video drivers you will have to re install them so make sure they are available for the new version.

Comment: I have FGLRX proprietary driver I believe, what I changed is just windows manager, from Unity to Gnome 3

Comment: Posted a Q [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/286844/101774). You might find the **"Notes on changes"** part useful.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This solution might not hold for distribution upgrades as such. See comments. To be confirmed.

You can always run `sudo apt-get --simulate dist-upgrade` and see if you get any errors. Always make a backup if your files are important for you or someone else.

Comment: This does ***NOT*** simulate an upgrade from one distribution to another. [Ref. -> Maintenance commands](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto).

Comment: I thought it does simulate. It did nothing so I assumed there is no way to upgrade my system yet, but today I saw in my update check that I can upgrade to 13.04, tried --simulate dist-upgrade but it did nothing again so, yes, I can't simulate dist upgrade, it was mistake.

Comment: @martin: I'm looking into it as well. Previous upgrades has been a disaster each time. Haven't found any good solution yet.